# How to ignore double quotes when reading CSV file in Pyspark?

Tags: pyspark, databricks

I have a CSV file like:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eLRUE.png)

```
ID, Tags
1,"""ApplicationID "": ""9AAG033396"",""Environment "": ""PROD"",""Remarks"": "" EUC Personal Desktop"""
2,"""ApplicationID "": ""9AAG033396"",""Environment "": ""PROD"",""Remarks"": "" EUC Personal Desktop"""
3,"""Remarks"": "" EUC Personal Desktop"",""ApplicationID "": ""9AAG033396"",""Environment "": ""PROD"""
```

Sample Tags values are given below.

```
"cluster": "csp-csp-cluster","kubernetes_node": ""

"Project": "S4","Type": "Dev"

"ApplicationID": "BSN0002278","ClusterId": "0803-071102-1n1kbom","ClusterName": "Riskman Quaitification Cluster","Creator": "xxxx@xxxx.com","DatabricksEnvironment": "workerenv-6764199050889752","Environment": "DEV","Remark": "EDP","RequestNo": "RITM0215195","Solution": "Riskman","Vendor": "Databricks","databricks-instance-name": "e82e5f2df9ae479bbb76766c48bdf3cc","x_Environment": "DEV"

"ApplicationID": "APP0005199","Environment": "Dev","Remark": "Buy@energy","RequestNo": "RITM0270765"

"ApplicationID": "","Environment": "","Remark": "","RequestNo": ""

"APM_ID": "empty","ApplicationID": "Empty","Environment": "PROD","Remark": "Logs","RequestNo": "empty"
```

I want to read it as a data frame in spark, where the values of every field are exactly as written in the CSV but without the quotes and need to create new column called ApplicationID.

Expected output:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/erQgV.png)

```
ID, Tags,ApplicationID
1,ApplicationID : 9AAG033396,Environment : PROD,Remarks:  EUC Personal Desktop,9AAG033396
2,ApplicationID : 9AAG033396,Environment : PROD,Remarks:  EUC Personal Desktop,9AAG033396
3,Remarks:  EUC Personal Desktop,ApplicationID : 9AAG033396,Environment : PROD,9AAG033396
```

The output i get

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zYNhi.png)

```
ID, Tags,ApplicationID
1,"""ApplicationID "": ""9AAG033396"",9AAG033396
2,"""ApplicationID "": ""9AAG033396"",9AAG033396
3,"""Remarks"": "" EUC Personal Desktop"",null
```

In pyspark I am reading like this:

```
df = spark.read\
  .option("header", "true")\
  .option("inferSchema", "true")\
  .option("delimiter", ",")\
  .option("escapeQuotes", "true")\
  .option("multiLine","true")\
  .option('quote','"')\
.csv(f"wasbs://{container}@{storage_account_name}.blob.core.windows.net/onetimeazamortizecostnew/onetimeazamortizecostnew/20230901-20231031/onetimeazamortizecostnew_17fcdeca-81ca-43e7-b181-36bc379e9644.csv")
```

```
`df2 = df.withColumn("ApplicationID", when(df.Tags.contains("ApplicationID"),substring('Tags', 23,10))
                                    .otherwise(''))`
```

I wonder if there is a way to accomplish this using the escape option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`escape` is exactly the option you are looking for. You want to set it to `"` so that double quote is quoted as `""`.

```
df = spark.read
  .option("header", "true")
  .option("inferSchema", "true")
  .option("escape",'"')
  .csv(f"wasbs://{container}@{storage_account_name}.blob.core.windows.net/onetimeazamortizecostnew/onetimeazamortizecostnew/20230901-20231031/onetimeazamortizecostnew_17fcdeca-81ca-43e7-b181-36bc379e9644.csv")
+---+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|ID | Tags                                                                                   |
+---+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|1  |"ApplicationID ": "9AAG033396","Environment ": "PROD","Remarks": " EUC Personal Desktop"|
|2  |"ApplicationID ": "9AAG033396","Environment ": "PROD","Remarks": " EUC Personal Desktop"|
|3  |"Remarks": " EUC Personal Desktop","ApplicationID ": "9AAG033396","Environment ": "PROD"|
+---+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

If you wrap your string in curly braces it can be parsed as JSON and you would be able to pull ApplicationID easily.

```
schema = StructType([StructField(c, StringType()) for c in ["ApplicationID ", "Environment ", "Remarks"]])
df.withColumn("Tags", from_json(concat(lit("{"), col(" Tags"), lit("}")), schema))\
  .withColumn("ApplicationID", col("Tags.ApplicationID "))
+---+-----------------------------------------+-------------+
|ID |Tags                                     |ApplicationID|
+---+-----------------------------------------+-------------+
|1  |{9AAG033396, PROD,  EUC Personal Desktop}|9AAG033396   |
|2  |{9AAG033396, PROD,  EUC Personal Desktop}|9AAG033396   |
|3  |{9AAG033396, PROD,  EUC Personal Desktop}|9AAG033396   |
+---+-----------------------------------------+-------------+
```

Note: you seem to have weird spaces in your CSV (like in `"ApplicationID "`). Not sure if that's how it looks like, but I wrote my code examples to match it.

Comment: Thanks for the solution @kombajn. i am getting below error 

**AnalysisException: [INVALID_SCHEMA.PARSE_ERROR] The input schema "schema" is not a valid schema string. Cannot parse the schema:
Unrecognized token 'schema': was expecting (JSON String, Number, Array, Object or token 'null', 'true' or 'false')
 at [Source: (String)"schema"; line: 1, column: 7]**

Comment: Sorry, missed a line on pasting - edited now

Comment: Tags values are not fixed. its means schema is not fixed sometime it has 2 key value pairs or 4 or null. sample cases are pasted. @kombajn

Comment: This doesn't matter. You might specify only ApplicationID if that's the only thing you use (`schema = StructType([StructField("ApplicationID ", StringType())])`). JSON reader is permissive by default, extra fields will be ignored and missing fields will be set to null.